# Are Playstation 4 communications really harder to monitor?

Tags: encryption, monitoring, instant-messaging

I have [read on the net](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2015-11-16-sony-responds-to-claim-ps4-used-for-terrorist-communications) that authorities are having troubles monitoring Playstation 4 communications.
As usual the news are very non technical.

What makes the Playstation 4 network harder to intercept?

Comment: Is it possible that they were referring to some sort of P2P communication? I have no idea if PlayStation does that, but I wouldn't be surprised if their servers merely brokered P2P sessions.

Comment: @forest Yes, possibly. That would not make it possible to snoop by just tapping into Sony's servers. But re-reading my question after a few years in cybersecurity I'm 100% confident the news is just sensational and there's nothing true on the technical ground. I even notice only now that those statements came from Belgium, one of the worst EU country in terms of anti-terrorism intelligence, I think they just tried to find a scapegoat.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Many of the news were just sensational news, not actual. There have been reports surfacing after this that security agencies monitor xbox and playstation communications. It came up as a playstation was found in one of the Paris attackers flats. It was baseless and been debunked quickly (https://motherboard.vice.com/read/how-the-baseless-terrorists-communicating-over-playstation-4-rumor-got-started) however that didn't stop the hoax.

The communications also don't use crypto as opposed to many better communication techniques for secret communications.

**So the answer is, its quite easy to intercept and Sony probably helps law-enforcement do it already. Some reports even say they are also using algorithms to search for suspicious activity themselves.**

Comment: Sony are not exactly masters of security themsevles - [Sony hacked yet again, plaintext passwords, e-mails, DOB posted](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2011/06/sony-hacked-yet-again-plaintext-passwords-posted/)

Answer (score 3):

As the article does not go into detail, I am left to suspicion.

I suppose Sony does not use strong crypto; else, it would not be 'hard' but 'very hard' to get plain text. (cf. Apple ./. FBI)

There is however another aspect:

The network is huge, with a big number of active users, voice communication in masses amongst fellow gamers and vast possibilities to for example join a game session collectivly and use team voice communication to communicate.

**It gets increasingly hard to find the needle in a haystack, the larger the haystack grows.**

Note: This also assumes there is not already a warrant in place for a specific person, as the communication of a single person's account might very well be easily tracked by law enforcement with of without the help of Sony.

Comment: I thought so, the whole thing about the haystack I mean, but the same apply to WhatsApp. So basically it is harder because gamers use voice communication?

Comment: Supposed that it actually is hard and not [a rumor](https://motherboard.vice.com/read/how-the-baseless-terrorists-communicating-over-playstation-4-rumor-got-started), that is what I'd suspect. I guess voice recognition for arabic languages might not be top notch, too.

Comment: What could make recognition of tone/catch-phrases could also be a little bit harder, if players play games where they need to collaborate and plant a bomb or kill a lot of people. I would recon it is very hard to decide for a software if a group of gamers is talking about an ingame plan or outgame...